# OpenCV installation for pc

Tags: python, opencv, pip

what does this mean? DEPRECATION: textract 1.6.5 has a non-standard dependency specifier extract-msg<=0.29.*. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of textract or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming dependency specifiers. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063?

I am trying to install pip install opencv-python

Comment: I think the `.*` has to be dropped from `extract-msg<=0.29.*`  The suggestion is correct, either a newer version of the package will have a compliant dependency specifier, or you could contact the author of the package to update their package accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to install `textract`, `pip` checks for `textract`'s dependencies. The problem is that `textract` specifies some of its dependencies in an old-fashioned (deprecated) way. Specifically, line 8 in [this file](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/blob/master/requirements/python) follows a format that pip is deprecating, hence the warning you get.

To go ahead without any warnings, first install or upgrade `extract-msg` manually,

```
pip install extract-msg --upgrade
```

and then `pip install textract` normally. Repeat if you find a similar warning for other dependencies.

Comment: What does this mean? ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
textract 1.6.5 requires beautifulsoup4~=4.8.0, but you have beautifulsoup4 4.12.2 which is incompatible.
textract 1.6.5 requires extract-msg<=0.29.*, but you have extract-msg 0.45.0 which is incompatible.
textract 1.6.5 requires six~=1.12.0, but you have six 1.14.0 which is incompatible.

Comment: It means that in order to install `textract` you need to install the right versions of its dependencies. You can do this manually using pip and appending the version to the packages `textract` requires, e.g. `pip install beautifulsoup4.8.0`. Note however that this may or may not break other packages in your machine. 

Looking at the repo for `textract` on github, it looks like it hasn't been updated in a long time. Maybe it's time to move on from it or maybe contact the maintainers if you depend critically on the package?

Comment: Related: other people had your same issue before you: https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/476