# DEPRECATION: pyodbc 4.0.0-unsupported has a non-standard version number

Tags: pip, pyodbc, deprecated

I am trying to download a framework and it seems that it is successfully installed but when I call dora --help, the command is not found. I think it has probably something to do with the DEPRECATION message but I am not sure what it is.

When I visit the discussion website stated (Discussion can be found at `https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063`) I couldn't understand anything or there wasn't sufficient information. I tried to upgrade to its latest version of dora but it seems that the problem is still there. Thank you and any help is appreciated!

ps also I tried to follow the answer in this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76973952/opencv-installation-for-pc`  i.e. `pip install extract-msg --upgrade` and then `pip install pyodbc` afterwards. But the same error appears again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [discussion](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063) you are being pointed to, it's [PEP 440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/) in effect.
The warning message you are seeing just says that particular package installed has a version number that doesn't conform to the new versioning standard for python packages.

If the package is actively maintained, a newer version that follows the standards must be available. Thus upgrading the package to the latest available version may solve the problem:

```
$ pip install -U pyodbc
```

Or

```
$ pip install --upgrade pyodbc
```